# Shutter reloaded for Next-Gen gallery -- smaller images and the title from alt attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

Sorry if this question is out of the place, but I didn't find any information about it at other places on the net... :-(

So, I have a Shutter-box javascript Lightbox, that I need to modify.

The Shutterbox script is here (already customised a bit): http://pastebin.com/g5qTF86H

The page where it is used: http://www.mrsherskin.com/collections/subconscious-levitation

1). By default this script doesn't take the alt of the images it takes for lightboxing, just the title attribute of it. I would like to set up a variable in this script to put the image's alt attribute as a title above the picture. I would use this jQuery script for it inserted in the showImg initialisation, but I don't know how could I set up a variable that inserts this alt tag read from the respective images:

```
var ImgTitle = jQuery('<div id="img-title"><h1 class="entry-title">Alt title</h1></div>');
jQuery(ImgTitle).appendTo('#shWrap');
```

2.) I would like to accommodate the size of the shown image so that 2-3 lines of description text could fit under it. Unfortunately I didn't find the part of the script that calculates the size of the lightboxed image, where to change it?

Any help please?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I dug a bit into the code and to me it seems that this part is responsible for getting the title variable (on lines 58-60) `T = ( L.title && L.title != shfile ) ? L.title : '';
           
            shutterLinks[i] = {link:L.href,num:inset,set:setid,title:T}` I tried setting a new `L.alt` attribute like the title T variable, but it didn't work... For changing the size I still don't have a clue where to look for it...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks so much for the answer about how to get the image alt attribute, it worked perfectly for me! I was a little confused about where to put the code that you provided, so in case any one else had the same issue I hope I can help clarify.

Find the following code snippet (should be around line 68 in shutter-reloaded.js which is in the shutter folder of the NextGen Gallery plugin):

```
shutterLinks[i] = {link:L.href,num:inset,set:setid,title:T}
```

Change that line to the following:

```
shutterLinks[i] = {link:L.href,num:inset,set:setid,title:T, alt: ALT}
```

Directly above that line you just changed, add the following:

```
ALT = jQuery(L).children('img').attr('alt');
```

I then found the following line:

```
NavBar = '<div id="shTitle"><div id="shPrev">' + prevlink + '</div><div id="shNext">' + nextlink + '</div><div id="shName">' + shutterLinks[ln].title + '</div>' + imgNum + '</div>';
```

And changed it to this:

```
NavBar = '<div id="shTitle"><div id="shPrev">' + prevlink + '</div><div id="shNext">' + nextlink + '</div><div id="shName">' + shutterLinks[ln].alt + '</div><div id="shCaptionLine">' + shutterLinks[ln].title + '</div>' + imgNum + '</div>';
```

Hope this helps!

-RG

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the solutions:

(1) I fetched the alt of the images under shutterbox rel-links by this jQuery method:

```
ALT = jQuery(L).children('img').attr('alt');
```

Added it to the shutterLinks object:

```
shutterLinks[i] = {link:L.href,num:inset,set:setid,title:T, alt: ALT}
```

Then inserted this variable in a new jQuery object, under the make function:

```
var ImgTitle = jQuery('<div id="img-title"><h1>' + shutterLinks[ln].alt + '</h1></div>');
jQuery(ImgTitle).prependTo('#shWrap');
```

(2) I found the part which scales down the large images (if image size is bigger than viewport size), and added to the end a shrink by 30 px

```
TI.style.width = (TI.width - 30) + 'px'; // add side padding
TI.style.height = (TI.height - 30) + 'px'; // add bottom padding
```

---

Update suggested by [Rachel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1135099/rachel):

To put this code, follow these steps:

Find the following code snippet (should be around line 68 in shutter-reloaded.js which is in the shutter folder of the NextGen Gallery plugin):

```
shutterLinks[i] = {link:L.href,num:inset,set:setid,title:T}
```

Change that line to the following:

```
shutterLinks[i] = {link:L.href,num:inset,set:setid,title:T, alt: ALT}
```

Directly above that line you just changed, add the following:

```
ALT = jQuery(L).children('img').attr('alt');
```

Then find the following line:

```
NavBar = '<div id="shTitle"><div id="shPrev">' + prevlink + '</div><div id="shNext">' + nextlink + '</div><div id="shName">' + shutterLinks[ln].title + '</div>' + imgNum + '</div>';
```

And change it to this:

```
NavBar = '<div id="shTitle"><div id="shPrev">' + prevlink + '</div><div id="shNext">' + nextlink + '</div><div id="shName">' + shutterLinks[ln].alt + '</div><div id="shCaptionLine">' + shutterLinks[ln].title + '</div>' + imgNum + '</div>';
```